# What does 'of a just,as of a' mean in this quote from Neitzsche mean?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

Considerate. The wish not to annoy anyone or injure anyone can be an equally good indication **of a just, as of a** fearful disposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the author has avoided repetition of the word *disposition* by omitting it in the first case. If he had not omitted it this part of the sentence would read **of a just disposition as of a fearful disposition** which might be clearer but would be somewhat more clumsy.

The author is saying that there are two reasons why people might act considerately: those with a *just disposition* have an inherent tendency to act out of a sense of fairness, equability and justice while those with a *fearful disposition* have an inherent tendency to act out of a fear of upsetting or angering others. 
The author says that a considerate person is equally likely to have either disposition but, by putting the fearful disposition second, is suggesting that people in general consider the fearful disposition to be a more common cause of considerate action.